# Exit code 13 from Perl's system() command?

Tags: perl

I am trying to call system commands from perl, using `system()`.

That usually works fine, but when I don't start the perl script myself, but have a compiled C program run it using the C `popen()` function, then perl is not able to execute its system commands. Perl's `system()` then returns with exit code 13.

It works only if I use the backticks in Perl, instead of `system`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Backticks return the standard output of the executed process, not the return value. That may explain why you're seeing it "work" with backticks-- your not actually getting the return value.

Comment: @Evan: I can see the stderr output of my process when I start it with the backticks. When I start it with `system()` I don't see anything, but get the bad return value ...

Comment: I noticed that also the `pclose()` function in my C program returns code 13, after executing the perl script using `popen`. Maybe it's the system setup here ...

Comment: You might want to check permissions.  An exit code of 13 typically is an access denied.

Comment: Strange. I don't know why `pclose` would give this error. I can see that it successfully executed the perl script.

Comment: Not enough information, but I'd bet it's an environment issue.

Comment: You may want to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to see some of your code/output.  Here's my guess at the root cause of your problem.

First, signal 13 equates to SIGPIPE, which in this case seems to indicates the perl process is attempting to write to a pipe (i.e. STDOUT/STDERR), but nothing is there to read it.

I tested a bit and my question is, are you handling the output from the the script within your C program?  In my tests, simply processing the output of the perl script avoided the SIGPIPE error.

Signal 13 produced:

```
fp = popen("/home/chuckx/perl-test/perl.pl","r");
status = pclose(fp);
```

Signal 13 avoided:

```
fp = popen("/home/chuckx/perl-test/perl.pl","r");

do {} while (fgets(output,80,fp) != NULL);

status = pclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer to an old question because I ran into a similar issue with `popen`.  If I run a command with `popen` (in a C/C++ program) and do not read any of the program output before calling `pclose', it returns a value of 13.  I think what's happening here is the running command cannot write all of its output to the pipe (because I never read anything) so when it is closed, it returns the value of 13.

If this is happening to anyone else, try to read the entire contents of the pipe/file returned by `popen` before closing it.